# Enforce user to enter specific date format

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, integrity

How can i enforce user to insert date only in "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss" format.

I understand that i can convert date anytime in any format using "CONVERT" function. But i like user to enter date in this format.

OR

How can i check if the format of entered date in database is correct or not. I like to use some function which check dates.

Comment: SQL Server is able to parse dates in many formats, there's really no need to limit them is there? -- are you inserting into a character field or a datetime field?

Comment: Sir i understand the fact that SQL Server is able to parse dates in many formats and i am aware of CONVERT function through which i can convert dates to many formats. But what i needed a function is to check and ensure that what we entering is correct, i am not sure but something like this will help like if i need to check for year than i can write something like this SELECT CASE WHEN 2000 LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'. I like to write something like this. Thank sin advance

Comment: SQL Server stores dates in a binary format, not a specific string format. The usual approach is to validate user input in the front-end application and pass it to the database as a correctly typed datetime parameter or value. Is this not suitable for your situation?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the date time format as a string or varchar value into the stored procedure. From here, you can convert it into the datetime format you require and store this into a second varchar variable in order to compare it with the first. Now that you have both the original varchar date, and the converted varchar date compare the two strings to see if they match.

```
CREATE FUNCTION checkdateformat (@myUserInput nvarchar(30)) RETURNS INTEGER AS

DECLARE @myDateString varchar(30)
SET @myDateString = @myUserInput

DECLARE @myCompareString varchar(30)
SET @myCompareString = (SELECT CONVERT(varchar(30),@myDateString,120) myDate)

DECLARE @myReturnValue INTEGER
SELECT @myReturnValue = CASE WHEN @myDateString = @myCompareString THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

RETURN @myReturnValue
```

Comment: @elvis.. Thnxx i willl check it and let you know.